# What is the best way to make mujoco environment of my own?

Tags: xml, openai-gym, openai-api, mujoco

I want to make a 3D model of reaction-wheel(https://github.com/simplefoc/Arduino-FOC-reaction-wheel-inverted-pendulum), using mujoco. And then I'll use reinforcement learning in mujoco environment to keep its balance. Is it possible to build a env like openai gym[mujoco], and then start learning? Or should I just write an xml file and use it directily with mujoco(or mujoco py)? I would like to get some advices about,

1. How to build xml files for mujoco
2. How can I import ai in it

I feel so desperate right now, since I couldn't find helpful documents or videos about making and using my own mujoco environment. I hope I can get help from you.

Answer (score 1):

Try using MuJoCo's native [simulate](https://mujoco.readthedocs.io/en/latest/programming.html#sasimulate) utility. It is made exactly for this. Modify your XML, reload in simulate, until it looks right. This [getting started](https://mujoco.readthedocs.io/en/latest/programming.html#getting-started) section has more information on running `simulate` locally.